# How do I copy old emails into a new IMAP account

Tags: microsoft-outlook, imap

I am a novice. How can I copy my old emails stored in Outlook 2010 via a POP account onto a new IMAP account that I have setup to replace the old POP account so that I can see all my old emails through a single IMAP account

Answer (score 1):

There might be easier ways depending on you control over the mail servers. But have you tried configuring the new account in outlook and copying messages from the old one to the new one. Haven't used outlook really but if you have troubles with it, you could try thunderbird and copy messages in bulks if single operation for all messages fails.

Answer (score 0):

You can export all your local E-mails to an external PST file. Then switch your configuration to IMAP and import all exported E-Mails into the IMAP folder structure.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just create a new IMAP account (with a new PST file) then drag your emails from your old PST file into a folder in the IMAP PST. It'll sync them automatically.